# How to create JAVA object from JSON string?

Tags: java, json, api, gson

I am creating an app that makes a GET Request to an API and receives a JSON and I need to create class that holds the information. This is what I have tried :

```
package apiwebapprequest;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class APIWebAppRequest {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Object obj = new Object();

    try {   
 URL url = new URL("xxx");
 URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
 String inputLine;

 while((inputLine = in.readLine())!= null){
     System.out.println(inputLine);

     in.close();
     gson.toJson(obj,inputLine);




 }

 }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}



}

}
```

This is the object class:

```
package apiwebapprequest;

public class Object {


private String cif;
private String data_creare;

public String getCif() {
    return cif;
}

public void setCif(String cif) {
    this.cif = cif;
}

public String getData_creare() {
    return data_creare;
}

public void setData_creare(String data_creare) {
    this.data_creare = data_creare;
}




}
```

On line 29 - > gson.toJson(obj,inputLine); it gives me an error. Can you please tell me how to do it ? I can`t find how to fix it or modify in other way that it works

The ideea is that i get out when i make request in inputLine I have json and I want to save the fields separate in Object properties

Comment: "it gives me an error" - are we supposed to guess the error? It would be easier to help you if you'd provide the error message for us.

Comment: Other than that, there is a lot of resources online on how to read/parse JSON in Java, eg. [this article](https://devqa.io/how-to-parse-json-in-java/)

Comment: check my answer you can use fromJson(json, Car.class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following way.

```
gson.toJson(obj); // is used to convert object to JSON
```

if you want to convert JSON to Java Object then you can use

```
gson.fromJson(json, Car.class);
```

Ex.

```
     public class Car {
            public String brand = null;
            public int    doors = 0;
   // add getter and setter

        }

String json = "{\"brand\":\"Jeep\", \"doors\": 3}";

Gson gson = new Gson();

Car car = gson.fromJson(json, Car.class);
```

Comment: you hard-coded the values, how can i take from variable that contains json ?

Comment: @SECI If you don't know the structure of the JSON data beforehand, you can use [the low-level Parser API of Gson](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html), e.g. `JsonParser.parseString(jsonString)` will return a [JsonElement](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) object which you can then analyze further.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the entire response first in the `while` loop and then convert to json after `while` loop ends.
You can modify your code something like

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while((inputLine = in.readLine())!= null){
     System.out.println(inputLine);
     sb.append(inputLine +"\n");
     in.close();
 }
gson.toJson(obj,sb.toString());
```

Comment: It says no suitable method found for toJson , do you know how to use Gson can you please help me with the correct method ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do `SoModel model = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), SoModel.class);` where SoModel is the java model class similar to structure of json response of service

Answer (score 0):

Try using `gson.toJson(obj,inputLine)` after the while loop.

Suppose the json is

```
{
"foo":"bar",
"foo1":"bar1"
}
```

Each line is not a valid JSON.
Hence you need to read the entire string 1st and then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson class `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`.

Following is how you can parse the json to the class:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass myClass = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
```